# How to do the calculation in the table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

When I entered the order no it fetches the ponumber, podate, partyname and that table and i have written in AJAX to fetch the data that I have done.now I want to do some changes in the qty column if I have change any value the whole table of qty should be added and displayed in total text box using JavaScript. How to do the calculation of this table?

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#orderno').on('input change',function(){
         var orderno = $("#orderno").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Inventory/Orderfetch",
        data: {
                orderno:orderno
        },
        datatype: 'json',   
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Product_Name_div').html(data); 
        }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Model:

```
function fetch_item($orderno){
 $this->db->where("orderno",$orderno);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->join('item_master', 'item_master.id = order_item.itname', 'left');
  $this->db->from('order_item');
  $query_result = $this->db->get()->result();
  $output = '<center><table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb2">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sno</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Wgt</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
  <tbody>';            

      if($query_result !='false'){
       $i=0; 

foreach ($query_result as $key => $value) { 

$output .='<tr> 
<td><input style="width:50px" name="sno[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->sno.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:250px" name="itemname[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->itemname.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:80px" name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->qty.'" id="qty_'.$i.'" onchange="calculate('.$i.')"></td> 
<td><input style="width:90px" name="wgt[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
<td><input style="width:150px" name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
</tr>'; 
$i++;
}
$output .="</tbody>
</table></center>";
echo $output;
}
}
```

Calculation code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(id){ 

 var tds = document.getElementById('tb2').getElementsById('input');
 var sum = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) 
 var qty=$("#qty_"+id).val(); 

alert(qty);

} 
</script>
```

From this I got a qty value, but I don't know how to sum this qty of the table.

Comment: If you are trying to access multiple DOM elements you should be using getElementsByClassName, in the other hand getElementsById doesn't exist since an element ID should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class in qty field and loop through its value

```js
function calculate(id){ 
 var total_qty = 0;
 var qty = document.getElementsByClassName("qty_cls");
 for(var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++)
 {
       if(qty[i].value != ''){
    total_qty += parseFloat(qty[i].value);
          }
 }
  alert(total_qty);

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb2">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sno</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Wgt</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr> 
<td><input style="width:50px" name="sno[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="1" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:250px" name="itemname[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="1" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:80px" name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs qty_cls" value="1" id="qty_1" onchange="calculate()"></td> 
<td><input style="width:90px" name="wgt[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
<td><input style="width:150px" name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td><input style="width:50px" name="sno[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'1" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:250px" name="itemname[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="2" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:80px" name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs qty_cls" value="2" id="qty_2" onchange="calculate()"></td> 
<td><input style="width:90px" name="wgt[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
<td><input style="width:150px" name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td><input style="width:50px" name="sno[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'3" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:250px" name="itemname[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="3" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:80px" name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs qty_cls" value="3" id="qty_3" onchange="calculate()"></td> 
<td><input style="width:90px" name="wgt[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
<td><input style="width:150px" name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please check for blank value in side loop other wise it give NaN error .i have just edit for it.

Comment: it is not necessary always the qty has a value it is fetching from another table any way thankyou so much